# Python requests, how to send json request without " "

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

my code looks like

```
            data = {
                "undelete_user":'false'
            }
            data_json = json.dumps(data)
            print(data_json)
```

Output is:

```
{"undelete_user": "false"}
```

i need output to be without "" so it can look like

```
{"undelete_user": false}
```

otherwise when i send request, i will get "failed to decode JSON" error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json


data = {
    "undelete_user": False
}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
print(data_json)
```

All you had to do was remove 'false' and put False, because you're considering your false as a string, and it should be a boolean. 
I hope it helped!

Comment: ohhh, thank you, was searching for it for almost day